# Visible area of winform

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I get the visible area of a winform?

I tried accessing Height\Width properties but I get the size of the full window (With the minimize, close and enlarge buttons)
how can I get only the part that I can manipulate without the tool-buttons in the head of the form?

Comment: Is `ClientRectangle` / `ClientSize` what you are looking for?

Comment: Can you please try to re-phrase your question, it is not clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean [Form.ClientSize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9278sfx2(v=vs.90).aspx).

> The size of the client area of the form is the size of the form
>   excluding the borders and the title bar. The client area of a form is
>   the area within a form where controls can be placed. You can use this
>   property to get the proper dimensions when performing graphics
>   operations or when sizing and positioning controls on the form. To get
>   the size of the entire form, use the Size property or use the
>   individual properties Height and Width.